# Colouring a plotly shape according to a value in a 'Classification' column

Tags: python, plotly

I am attempting to create a plot that represents 2 different datasets.  They have been added as 2 separate traces.  The first is a simple scatter plot and the second is a series of rectangles that i would like to colour in different ways depending on a 'Classification' value.  The rectangles represent that duration of an 'event'. I can colour the rectangles using the fillcolor option, but at the moment i only seem to be able to set the colour to a single value e.g. 'red'.

The 2 data frames would look like this:

```
df1
Datetime, Frequency_hz
15/08/2023 09:09:22, 1575422000
15/08/2023 10:10:32, 1575452000
15/08/2023 10:10:35, 1572322000
15/08/2023 11:11:54, 1575432000

events_df
Date_Start_Time, Date_End_Time, Classification, Band
15/08/2023 09:23:22,15/08/2023 09:35:12, Class 1,A
15/08/2023 09:43:40,15/08/2023 09:50:47, Class 2,A
15/08/2023 10:13:44,15/08/2023 10:15:32, Class 3,A
15/08/2023 11:33:11,15/08/2023 11:39:23, Class 4,B

My code looks like this:

# Loading data
DATA = 'C:\work\20230815_UTC.csv'
EVENT_DATA = r"C:\work\events.csv"
BAND = 'A'

df = pd.read_csv(DATA)
events_df = pd.read_csv(EVENT_DATA)

# Filter for band
events_df = events_df[(events_df['Band'] == BAND)]

# Filter data for specific weekday
events_df = events_df.loc[events_df['Date_Start_time'].dt.weekday == 1] # 1= Tues, 2=Wed, 3=Thurs


df = pd.read_csv(DATA)
# Create plots 
fig1 = go.Figure()
fig1.add_scatter(
        x=df1.Datetime,
        y=df1.Frequency_hz,
        mode="markers",
        name="Points",
        showlegend=True
    )

# Dictionary for colouring classes
colours = {'Class 1':'red','Class 2':'violet',
                'Class 3':'aqua','Class 4':'brown'}

# Loop through events table and plot

for i in events_df.index:
    start_time = events_df.loc[i,"Date_Start_time"]
    end_time = events_df.loc[i,"Date_End_time"]
    colour = events_df.loc[i,"Classification"]
    fig1.add_vrect(x0=start_time,
                  x1=end_time,
                  fillcolor=colours['Classification'],
                  opacity=0.5,
                  name='Events'
                  )

# Update various layout parameters
fig1.update_layout(
    title=f"Events on 15th August 2023",
    xaxis_title="Time (UTC)",
    yaxis_title="Frequency (Hz)",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="RebeccaPurple"
    )
)
fig1.show()
```

My code, shows that I have created a dictionary, 'colours' and within the loop I have tried to set the value of the fillcolor option to whatever the 'Classification' value is.  This doesn't work, and i get a 'KeyError: 'Classification' message.  If i set the fillcolor to 'red' it works, but all rectangles are coloured red. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how i might be able to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: Your column names in the code do not match the column names in your sample data. Also, what is `event_colour`? Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, thanks, i've edited it.  The real dataset has many more columns, so i've simplified the dataframes and in doing so i must have made a typo. Event_colour should have been the 'colours' dictionary.  This is the bit that doesn't work

Comment: Is the actual data, ' Class 1' ? Does the class string contain any spaces in front of it? Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the classification column not just the index

```
for idx, vals in events_df['Classification'].items():
    start_time = events_df.loc[idx,"Date_Start_Time"]
    end_time = events_df.loc[idx,"Date_End_Time"]
    fig1.add_vrect(x0=start_time,
                  x1=end_time,
                 fillcolor=colours[vals],
                  opacity=0.5,
                  name='Events'
                  )
```

[image]

Comment: YESSSS!!!!  Thanks you so much, that works and is just what i'm after. Many thanks